# Unable to exchange code for access token in node.js. Mailchimp API

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to use OAuth2 with the Mailchimp API, and I am following their documentation to the letter, but I am unable to complete step 4. At this step, I exchange the code I received from the authorization screen for the token. Per the documentation, this can be done in curl like so:

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token' \
--data "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&redirect_uri={encoded_url}&code={code}" \
--include
```

I attempted to convert this to work on node.js by writing this:

```
        var dataString = 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=' + clientid + '&client_secret=' + clientsecret + '&redirect_uri=' + encodedurl + '&code=' + url.parse(req.url, true).query.code;

        var options = {
            url: 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token',
            method: 'POST',
            data: dataString
        };

        function callback(error, response, body) {
            if (!error) {
                console.dir(JSON.stringify(body));
            }
            else{
                console.dir(error); 
            }
        }

        request(options, callback);
```

When I make the request.debug = true, I see that I am getting a 400 error. The message sent to the console is a bunch of garbled characters though. When I use these same variables and endpoints to authenticate through Postman though, it works fine, so the issue is not with the variables or the API itself.

I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here. The request I am making seems almost identical what is written in curl in the documentation. So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The issue was in the header of the request. There are two ways to fix this. The first is to use "form" instead of "data". *Request* includes a "content-type: x-www-form-urlencoded" header automatically if the option "form" is used.

```
var options = {
    url: 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST',
    form: dataString
};
```

I am not sure what header is used when the "data" option is used, or if no content-type is declared at all. Either way, if you choose to continue to use the "data" option, you can manually declare a content-type header. This is the second possible solution.

```
var options = {
    url: 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: 
    { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: dataString
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, did you forget to define `request`?

```
var request = require("request");
```

Comment: Since you probably already did, the other thing you could look at is the code snippet used in Postman to make the request. Inside Postman, under save, you should see "Code". Click on that and then select "Node.js Request" - then compare what you have in your script to that. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of tries, I figured out. You can use code only once. So make sure you use code you get from redirect URI only once.

With new code use this code

```
const dataString = "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id="+client_id+"&client_secret="+client_secret+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+"&code="+req.body.code
    var options = {
        url: 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers:
        {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        form: dataString
    };
    function callback(error, response, body) {
      if (!error) {
        let str = JSON.stringify(body)
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        res.send(body)
      }
      else{
        console.dir(error);
        res.send(error)
      }

    }
    request(options, callback);
```